# "I went to..." vs "I was at..."

Tags: difference, verbs, past-tense

Instead of saying:

> I **went** to the hospital a month ago.

Is it acceptable to say:

> I **was at** the hospital a month ago.

Is either of these sentences preferred over the other?

Comment: it sounds alright.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you mean it:

> I was at the hospital a month ago

Means that you were physically inside of a hospital one month ago.

> I was in the hospital a month ago

Implies that you were ill and admitted as a patient.

So use "at" if you were visiting/working/wandering around, "in" if you were being treated.

Comment: I disagree with your last sentence. "In" sounds right if you were kept in the hospital (say, overnight or in a ward), but you can be seen and treated without being placed in a ward, similar to how GP's surgeries work. I would use "at" for those cases too.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, and in most cases can be used interchangably, though they can have slightly different connotations (a connotation is "an idea or feeling that a word invokes in addition to its literal or primary meaning" (from Google).

"I went to the hospital a month ago", literally means that one traveled to the hospital a month ago, but has the connotation that one went to seek medical treatment for one's self.

"I was at the hospital", literally means that one was present in the hospital, but could have arrived there before the indicated time period, but lacks the connotation of seeking medical care. Interestingly, "I was **in** the hospital" has the same literal meaning, but does have the connotation of receiving medical care, especially intensive care. Such as with the threat "I'll put you in the hospital".

Generally, at least in my region of the US, "I went to the hospital" would generally be used more, with "I was at the hospital" is generally only used to describe one's location. For example, if one's boss asks "where where you yesterday?", one response might be "I was at the hospital; my father went into surgery".